# ReflectionTypeLoadException Error running add-migration command in package manager console

Tags: c#, entity-framework, powershell, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF7 for a Windows 10 UWP.

This is an extreme source of frustration for me. I'm running the command `add-migration "test"` from the package manager console in Visual Studio 2015. I'm getting the error

> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or
>   more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property
>   for more information.

How the hell do you retrieve the `LoaderExceptions` property? Every blog post or stackoverflow question I've looked at assumes that I've got access to this via C#, or a simple restart of VS2015 will fix this.

I'm not very familiar with `PowerShell`, but I have tried the following:

```
try { add-migration "test" } catch [System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException] {Write-Host "LoaderExceptions: $($_.Exception.LoaderExceptions)"}
```

Sadly, I don't get the error details I expected (on another note, how do you enable multiline in the console???).

Here's my project.json file

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.SQLite": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "FubarCoder.RestSharp.Portable": "3.1.0",
    "FubarCoder.RestSharp.Portable.OAuth": "3.1.0",
    "LightInject": "4.0.4",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.0.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "8.0.2"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "uap10.0": {}
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-arm": {},
    "win10-arm-aot": {},
    "win10-x86": {},
    "win10-x86-aot": {},
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win10-x64-aot": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please add Your Migration Config file?

Comment: @Aizen By migration file, do you mean my DbContext class?

Comment: No, not the DB context. Every EF have a migration config file when you enable migrations. It is automatically added in a folder Migrations. If you don't have any Migrations folder, then you didn't Activate Migrations at all. Maybe that is why, you're having some errors.

Comment: @Matt I was just wondering, did you find a solution to this problem? I am experiencing the same, and I have searched all around the net with no luck so far.
I even made a copy of the project with the same dependencies, adding one by one and doing a migration but there is no issue there. The new project was able to do the migration.

Comment: @boring32 - No solution, however I found the source. My entity objects implement interfaces from a separate class library (So they can be shared). To make things work, I've had to remove the reference to this library, and then include a C# file with the same interfaces, so everything is under one roof. More info here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3543

Comment: @Matt My problem got solved with the release of EF core 1.0. It was a combination of the release and the name of the Id field, which was renamed although I was using the appropriate annotations. By creating a public property <ClassName>Id the creation of the public key was successful and the migration proceeded.

Answer (score -1):

Do these using nuget package manager console
1- enable migration by "enable-migrations".
2- add new migration by " add-migrationb X" : X is custom migration name 
3- update database by "update-database"

Comment: Enable-Migrations is obsolete

Comment: Automatic Migration may cause data loose on some migrations such as change column name